# Spring rich client can not resolve artifact

Tags: spring

I want to setup a spring rich client application in eclipse, I modified the pom.xml file but seems to not be able to find the spring-richclient dependencies.

this is my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springRichclient.version>1.0.0</springRichclient.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.richclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-richclient-resources</artifactId>
        <version>${springRichclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.richclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-richclient-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springRichclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I get the following error when starting the server:

```
Could not find artifact org.springframework.richclient:spring-richclient-resources:jar:1.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

Comment: Well, spring-richclient-resources isn't in Maven Central. Which repository are you trying to pull it from?

Comment: default repository, but indeed when I added the repositories worked.

Comment: Yeah it's not *in* the default repo, mostly because it's a pretty dead project (no activity in almost 10 years).

Comment: do you have any recommendation for a java rich client application. And to be able to use the sprig framework with it.

Answer (score 0):

Added the repository tags and worked:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>springRichclientRepository</id>
            <name>Spring rich client repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/maven2repository</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>springRichclientSnapshotRepository</id>
            <name>Spring rich client snapshot repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/maven2snapshotrepository</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
</repository>
```